# hql not deleting query ok

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "delete from Attendance attend where attend.id in(Select att.id from Attendance att where att.dat= :dat and att.cls_id= :cls_id)"
    ).setDate("dat", dat).setShort("cls_id",cls_id); // delete all records with matching date and cls_id
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
// immediate save after delete in same transaction
for(Attendance a : absent){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(a);
}
```

I am trying to delete existing rows with particular criteria because the objects which I am saving may already exist in the table. But that delete is not working and duplicate values are getting inserted. Please let me know which part of the code is wrong.

Comment: Why such a complex query, and not just `delete from Attendance att where att.dat= :dat and att.cls_id= :cls_id`?

Comment: I changed it and made complex when it was not working, it was my silly mistake, may be i am too much sleepy and forgot to execute. Sorry guys, and thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

You are not executing the query, just passing the parameters. You need to call `executeUpdate()` method on your query:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from Attendance attend where attend.id in(Select att.id from Attendance att where att.dat= :dat and att.cls_id= :cls_id)")
                        .setDate("dat", dat).setShort("cls_id",cls_id).executeUpdate();
```